# Perl socket sending hash

Tags: perl, sockets

I am trying to create a socket client in Perl. The server side is a C program running on the local host.

I have to send a hash over the socket. Here is the piece of code I am using.

```
sub applyGlobalConfig {
    my ($globalConfig, $ignoreData) = @_;

    my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $PEER_HOST,
                                       PeerPort => $PEER_PORT,
                                       Proto    => "tcp",
                                       Type     => SOCK_STREAM)
          or die "Couldn't connect to $PEER_HOST:$PEER_PORT : $@\n";

    my $reconfigResult;

    print $socket "$113\n";

    close($socket);

    unless ($reconfigResult) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ERR_NULL;
}
```

Now, the question I have is, the `$globalConfig` will contain a hash reference, and I want to send this over a socket. I am unable figure out. I googled and found some reference to Dumper but couldn’t understand much. How do I send the hash over?

Comment: Do you want to send the hash reference as a number or as a string (just for the value of the reference), or do you want to send the constents of the hash (recursively)? The question is unclear, as is sending '$113'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to use [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.39/Storable.pm) module for this. Example:

Receive-side:

```
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Storable;
use Data::Dumper;

my   $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(Listen    => 5, LocalAddr => 'host',
                                 LocalPort => 9000,  Proto     => 'tcp');
while( my $s = $sock->accept ) {
    my $struct = Storable::fd_retrieve($s);
    print Dumper($struct);
}
```

Send-side:

```
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Storable;

my   $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => 'host',  PeerPort => 9000,
                 Type     => SOCK_STREAM, Proto     => 'tcp') || die "Fail: $!";
my $struct = {
    a => 1,
    b => [2,3,4]
};
Storable::nstore_fd($struct, $sock);
```

Tested by sending from i386 Linux to amd64 FreeBSD.

Also you can use Data::Dumper to make string from hash and then send over network but its dirty and buggy method.

**UPD:**

> But, I am struggling how to convert the values in the hash on perl side to a string separated by space.

Try to use join/map combination:

```
my $serialized = join("\n", map { "$_ ".$struct->{$_} } keys %$struct)."\n";
```

Probably on C side its easier to use null-terminated string:

```
my $keyvalue_count = scalar keys(%$struct);
my $serialized = join("\0", map { "$_\0".$struct->{$_} } keys %$struct)."\0";
```

In this simple case i'd prefer to use last variant since its native to C.

Comment: The receiver is written in C ...but maybe it just stores the data for later retrieval by Perl?

Comment: @ikegami Opps i failed to keep im mind this. In this case its really more complicated since hash implementation in plain C is not easy question. Probably its woth to stick with **Storable::fd_retrieve** using perlembed. Or maybe just send as text like `key = value\n`

Comment: as ikegami said, the server is a c program. it receives these as a struct containing argc and argv. One way I was thinking was to convert the values in the hash to strings separated by space. before sending it over. But, I am struggling how to convert the values in the hash on perl side to a string separated by space. Appreciate any help

Comment: looks good. let me try it. By the way cant I use,  my $globalData = sprintf ("%s %s %s\n", $OPCODE, $cfg->{"hisAge"}, $cfg->{"herAge"}) and then do print $socket $globalData;

Comment: @SreeramRavinoothala sure you can, but it may be painful to add new hash keys

Comment: Since the number of keys are static and limited, it should work. The values can be variable

Answer (score 6):

To send a data structure over a socket you have to "serialize" it into a byte stream. Then the receiving program has to deserialize it to reassemble the data structure.  If the receiving program is expecting the stream to be in a specific form, the sending program must produce the expected format.

If you are writing both sides, then you can choose a serialization format that makes sense for your situation, such as JSON or XML, either of which can represent a Perl hash.  However, without knowing much more detail about your specific situation, this is about all that can be provided in the way of an answer.